# Forecast and STL are sensitive to last few data points

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm working on a time series containing hourly data for 8 days. Using the R `forecast` package, I'm trying to predict future data with `stl`. If I use only 7 days data, things work fine, but when I add the last day, the predicted values drop strongly. My questions:

1. Visually the 8 days data still show a clear periodic trend, why
   forecast gives that result? Looking at the data, I see that the
   value of the last hour of the day drops to 0 sooner than in previous
   days. But why forecast are so sensitive with that?
2. Any advice for this situation? Any search keyword or reference that
   I should know for further reading?

Thank you.

```
xnn <- c(0.11, 0.28, 0.26, 0.27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.25, 
0.35, 0.42, 0.39, 0.17, 0.19, 0.36, 0.38, 0.41, 0.35, 0.33, 0.37, 
0.36, 0.33, 0.06, 0, 0.17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.17, 0.31, 0.23, 0.4, 
0.38, 0.33, 0.41, 0.34, 0.33, 0.41, 0.33, 0.34, 0.38, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.4, 0.38, 0.27, 0.17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.44, 0.39, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.38, 0.28, 0.36, 0.38, 0.43, 0.42, 0.44, 0.45, 0.41, 0.34, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 0.17, 0.17, 0.21, 0.42, 0.46, 0.42, 
0.46, 0.38, 0.34, 0.35, 0.37, 0.38, 0.36, 0.36, 0.38, 0.35, 0.36, 
0.39, 0.25, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0, 0, 0.28, 0.28, 0.42, 0.43, 
0.44, 0.41, 0.41, 0.37, 0.37, 0.31, 0.33, 0.32, 0.34, 0.29, 0.3, 
0.28, 0.22, 0.17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.17, 0.32, 0.38, 0.39, 
0.4, 0.37, 0.41, 0.45, 0.39, 0.35, 0.37, 0.33, 0.38, 0.37, 0.31, 
0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 0.1, 0.15, 0.19, 0.26, 0.38, 0.39, 0.39, 
0.38, 0.38, 0.42, 0.41, 0.4, 0.43, 0.41, 0.33, 0.28, 0.35, 0.39, 
0.26, 0.31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.23, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.43, 
0.41, 0.44, 0.43, 0.43, 0.41, 0.31, 0, 0)

require(forecast)
## hourly data
## 8 days (24*8 = 192 data points)
dput(xnn)

## using first 7 days, result is acceptable
x.ts <- ts(xnn[(1+24*0):(7*24)], frequency = 24)
fit <- stl(x.ts, s.window="periodic")
X11()
plot(fit)
X11()
plot(forecast(fit), type = "o")

## include one more day, unexpected result
x.ts <- ts(xnn[(1+24*0):(8*24)], frequency = 24)
fit <- stl(x.ts, s.window="periodic")
X11()
plot(fit)
X11()
plot(forecast(fit), type = "o")
```

[image: 7days]

[image: 8days]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last day drops to zero much sooner than earlier days. So the seasonally adjusted series has a big drop right at the end of your 8th day. The forecasts reflect this drop. It looks like you might be missing some observations in the last day.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for your great package :) In situations like this, is there any parameter that I can tune to ease out the effect on the seasonally adjusted series? If I throw away the last 7 points (of 24 points of the last day), then the forecast comes back to normal. It does not make sense (in practice) when I have 50 days of regular data and the forecast for the whole next 5 days drop just because of the last few points. Or do you suggest any better model/approach for such kinds of data? Thanks.